# Run unit tests on Save with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio

Has anyone managed to make a reasonably comfortable setup for their project where unit tests run on every save?

I currently have a split project -- An Android Application project, and a Java project that the android application depends upon. I write unit tests for the Java project and run them manually every now and then.

In my understanding, to make this happen as expected, I also want to have incremental builds for the Java project. I am not sure that this is feasibly possible while using Gradle with its current state of affairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse or IntelliJ with JUnit, you can use [InfiniTest](https://infinitest.github.io/) to run tests on save. InfiniTest only runs tests for code that has changed rather than running everything, so it's great for TDD. InfiniTest is completely decoupled from Gradle, so you don't have to worry about incremental builds.